# translating a sentence into predicate calculus

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am supposed to translate the following sentence into predicate calculus:

```
No Student likes the classroom.
```

S(x) : x is a student
C(x) : x likes the classroom

I am assuming that no Student means none or "not all" so Would I be correct to assume that the translation would be:

```
¬∀xS(x) -> C(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No student" is **not** "not all"; it is "all not".

The translation must be :

> > $∀x(S(x) → ¬C(x))$

which means "if $x$ is a student, then he does not like the classroom", i.e. "no student likes the classroom".

---

Your proposed translation :

> $¬∀x(S(x) \rightarrow C(x))$

is equivalent to :

> $\exists x \lnot (S(x) \rightarrow C(x))$

and thus to :

> $\exists x (S(x) \land \lnot C(x))$

that means : "there is some student that does not like the classroom".